# Anonymous JAX-RS Resources

Tags: java, jax-rs, soa

I am searching for any posibility to create JAX-RS Resources during runtime (for entity classes). Usually these classes get annotated with `@Path("/<resource>")` to identify them as resource class. Is it posible to create these classes during runtime, eg as anonymous class with custom paths?

Here an idea how it could look like, while abstract Service is a base implementation:

```
AnyType service = new AbstractService() {
  @Path("/<CustomResourceName>")
  public Collection<Resource> getAll() {
    return dao.getAll(Resource.class);
  }
}
```

After that of course the service must be registered somehow.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not having a prefix for all auto-generated Rest Resources?

Comment: That would not be the problem, the problem is to customize the path for each resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as simple as the following:

```
@Path("/dynamic-classes")
public class DynamicRestResource {
    private static final Map<String, Class<?>> CLASS_NAME_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, Class<?>>(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    {
            put(MyClass1.class.getSimpleName().toLowerCase(), MyClass1.class);
            put(MyClass2.class.getSimpleName().toLowerCase(), MyClass2.class);
                        //... put here your other classes.
            }}
    );
  private Class<?> getMappedClass(String mappedPath) {
    return CLASS_NAME_MAP.get(mappedPath);
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{className}")
  public Collection<?> getAll(@PathParam("className") String className) {
    //do some checks that there is such a path
    return dao.getAll(this.getMappedClass(className));
  }

  @DELETE
  @Path("/{className}/{entityId}")
  public Collection<?> deleteEntity(@PathParam("className") String className, @PathParam("entityId") Long entityId) {
    //do some checks that there is such a path
    return dao.delete(this.getMappedClass(className), entityId);
  }
}
```